# How to set default tab for initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

Currently [this webpage](http://jmoon.net/projects/phoenixrising/phoenixrising_p1.html) opens to the tab, "Freebies & Extras." I want it to open to the first tab, "Commonwealth & Council." I believe, by default, it will open to the first tab. I tried to locate where it is telling the browser to open it on the third tab but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the **active** to 0 in the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#Panels').tabs({
    active: 2,
    collapsible: false,
    activate: function(event, ui) {...
```

---

**UPDATE**

When you click the tab 0, then the page runs this code:

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: true,
   slideshow: false,
   itemWidth: 80,
   itemMargin: 5,
   asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: true,
   slideshow: false,
   sync: "#carousel"
});

//-----------------
$(window).resize();
//-----------------
```

Since you are not clicking this tab to start, this code is not running when the tab opens. You need to run the code by yourself. I suggest create a function and call it right after defining the tabs.

The full script would be (maybe something is misplaced, because I haven't run it):

```
function ClickedTab(carousel, slider){
   $(carousel).flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: true,
      slideshow: false,
      itemWidth: 80,
      itemMargin: 5,
      asNavFor: slider
   });

   $(slider).flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: true,
      slideshow: false,
      sync: carousel
   });

   //-----------------
   $(window).resize();
   //-----------------
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#Panels').tabs({
        active: 0,
        collapsible: false,
        activate: function(event, ui) {
          switch (ui.newPanel.index()) {
           case 0:
              ClickedTab("#carousel", "#slider"); break;
           case 1:
              ClickedTab("#carousel2","#slider2"); break;
          }
        }
    });
    ClickedTab("#carousel", "#slider")
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That works to open with the first tab but now the flexslider contained in that tab won't load unless I click out of that tab and click back into it. Would you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you are looking for:

```
$('div#Panels').tabs({
    active: 2,
```

The [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option tells the tab control which tab to display.

If you change the `active` value to `0` (or remove it altogether), it should display the first tab on page load.

---

Since the `activtate` event is not triggered for the initially displayed tab, you could move the code from the `activate` event handler into a separate function, and then call that function both in the `activate` event handler and when the page first loads.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function activateTab(index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:

                $('#carousel').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: true,
                    slideshow: false,
                    itemWidth: 80,
                    itemMargin: 5,
                    asNavFor: '#slider'
                });

                $('#slider').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: true,
                    slideshow: false,
                    sync: "#carousel"
                });

                //-----------------
                $(window).resize();
                //-----------------

                break;

            case 1:

                $('#carousel2').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: true,
                    slideshow: false,
                    itemWidth: 80,
                    itemMargin: 5,
                    asNavFor: '#slider2'
                });

                $('#slider2').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: true,
                    slideshow: false,
                    sync: "#carousel2"
                });

                //-----------------
                $(window).resize();
                //-----------------

            break;   
          }
    }

    $('div#Panels').tabs({
        active: 0,
        collapsible: false,
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            activateTab(ui.newPanel.index());
        }
    });

    activateTab(0);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works to open with the first tab but now the flexslider contained in that tab won't load unless I click out of that tab and click back into it. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @expansivelove - It's a shame it doesn't execute that code automatically, but it can be fixed. I have added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this. The script works great for tab 0 but the second flexslider, in tab 1, doesn't load when the tab is clicked. Nizam, who also answered this question, created a function, ClickedTab, to call after defining the tabs and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @expansivelove - Happy to hear you got this working. I see a mistake in the code I was showing. That should have been `ui.newPanel.index()`, instead of `ui.newPanel.index`.